# Project storage management in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

One of our projects' storage size is increasing rapidly, and I no longer know where to look to free space. In the Admin Area, the project storage details say the **Build Artifacts** are what I need to clean up :

[image: storage_details]

**What I've tried so far**

1. **Set up expire time for artifacts** - this doesn't seem to affect past artifacts, which are still taking up space
2. **House cleaning** - no visible changes noted
3. **Delete pipelines through the Rest API** - I later found out this does not seem to clean job artifacts and I should've erased jobs directly instead
4. **Check Gitlab's database** - no jobs/builds are linked to my project anymore (tables checked : **ci_builds** and **ci_job_atifacts**
5. **Rake commands** - Tested `sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:cleanup:orphan_job_artifact_files` until the number of deleted orphans reached 0; no effect on my project storage value; tested a couple other commands on [this page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/cleanup.html), to no avail

I've also found [this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/223793) that seems to indicate that storage cleanup management doesn't yet seem to be properly (easily) handled by gitlab yet.

**Questions**

1. What is counted in a given project's storage value ?
2. How do I clean up once what I've tried so far hasn't had any influence ?

Comment: It sounds like you have access to the server, so you can check the directory on disk where artifacts are stored. By default they're in `/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts`, but if the path was modified you can find it in the `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` file under the key `gitlab_rails['artifacts_path']`

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem using Gitlab 13.9.5. By executing the mentioned rake task, the artifacts were removed from disc. The artifacts folder contains < 1 GB of data. However, two of my projects are still showing about 4 GB under storage.